# I need to verify that a variable exists in a database. Shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a query that gives me a dataframe. When I receive the data frame, I use this code to make some numeric variables:

```
variables_numeric<-c("A","B","C","D")
datos[, variables_numeric] <- lapply(datos[, variables_numeric], as.numeric)
```

But when for some reason one of these columns does not come in the df, I get this error:

```
Warning: Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected
```

There is some way to avoid this? I was thinking in use ifelse to check first if the dataframe countain the variable.

Comment: why arent they numeric to start with? i would use `type.convert` on the whole data frame, but that doesnt force columns to be numeric like you are doing. you could try a for loop instead `for (v in variables_numeric) if (!is.null(datos[[v]])) datos[[v]] <- as.numeric(datos[[v]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can first find the variables in `datos` and then apply your code logic:

```
datos <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
variables_numeric <- c("A","B","C","D")
variables_in_df <- variables_numeric[variables_numeric %in% names(datos)]

datos[, variables_in_df] <- lapply(datos[, variables_in_df], as.numeric)
```